# As yet + past simple/present perfect

Tags: meaning, grammar, tenses, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

I was unable to find out the rules here and what is the difference:

> As yet, he has not received the package.
>    As yet little was known of
>   the causes of the disease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first, *as yet* means ‘up until this time’. In the second, it means ‘up until that time’.

Comment: That is strange :( I thought that "as yet" means "until now". Shouldnt it be like "until then" in the second sentence?

Comment: @Pietro: Yes. As yet = until now/then =  until this/that time.

Comment: This isn't the reason for the presence/absence of the perfect aspect. Present: *"As yet, little is known of the cause of the disease." "As yet, he has not received the package."* Past: *"As yet, little was known of the cause of the disease." "As yet, he had not received the package."* There are four possible choices here.

Answer (score 2):

*Yet* is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) (NPI), and that means that it -- and constructions that it's in like *as yet* -- can only occur grammatically within the scope or a [Negative Trigger](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) construction.

That in turn means that in the two example sentences given:

- *As yet, he has **not** received the package.*
- *As yet **little** was known of the causes of the disease.*

it is the negative triggers (respectively, *not* and *little*) that license the use of *yet*.

We can easily see this from the fact that affirmative variations are ungrammatical:

- **As yet, he has received the package.*
- **As yet much was known of the causes of the disease.*

Executive Summary: What a word -- especially a little word -- is **supposed** to mean has little to do with its syntax. Dictionaries are for words in isolation; grammars are for words in sentences.